# When configuring a PfR Master Controller, after pointing to the border router, which interfaces are specified?

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios

[image: Topology]

Ok so hopefully this is a quick answer. All of the explanations on the web I have found have been unspecific in this regard, so I apologize in advance for simplicity.

In the example topology, when configuring the MC and specifying the information of the BR (R3), whose interfaces are you specifying?

For example config:

```
<R5>oer master
<R5>border X.X.X.X (Loopback on R3 or whatever)
<R5>interface (INT) internal
<R5>interface fa0/0 external
<R5>interface s1/2 external
```

For those two interface commands, do I have that correct? Are we specifying the interfaces on the BR or the MC? I feel like it should be the interfaces of the BR being specified on the MC, but at the same time I'm not entirely sure how the MC would understand what those interfaces are being referenced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question for the sake of anyone else who may have the same question:

Yes, you would need to specify the interfaces of the border router. Through communication between the BR and MC, they can refer to one another's interfaces despite not having direct knowledge of them.

Comment: You should accept your answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.